# How to exit Fullscreen and go back to portrait orientation in an Xcode app

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have an app where when pressing a button it goes to a virtual tour web link to, what I did was change also that ViewController orientation to landscape and its in fullscreen, what I'm failing to achieve is to press back and go back to portrait orientation
.

the viewcontroller code:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
var webView: WKWebView!



override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return  .landscapeRight
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeRight
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // 1
    let url = URL(string: "https://kuula.co/share/collection/7qFsC?logo=1&card=1&info=0&logosize=72&fs=0&vr=0&zoom=1&sd=1&initload=0&autorotate=0.3&autopalt=1&thumbs=-1&margin=14")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    
  let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    
    // 2
   /*let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
    toolbarItems = [refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false*/
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    }

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

In my storyboard segue property is where I changed the "Presentation" to fullscreen.

I've tried add a back button but that doesn't work. And if I somehow go back the app remains in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dismiss the modal viewcontroller

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried this method, however automatically goes back in a matter of seconds